# What does it mean for domain to exhaust a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

I am trying to understand a proof of the statement: Axiom of Choice => Hypothesis of Cardinal Comparability. In the proof it says: "The idea is to define (using AoC) an expansive mapping on the set of partial injections which extends properly each partial injection: p: A $\rightharpoonup$ B whose domain does not *exhaust* A and whose range does not *exhaust* B...

I want to know what it means to exhaust in this instance.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Exhaust" just means "be all of".  So we are considering partial injections whose domain is a *proper* subset of $A$ and whose image is a *proper* subset of $B$, the idea being that given such a partial injection, you can always extend it to one more element of $A$ in the domain and one more element of $B$ in the image.